# StepContribution or ChunkContext for ExecutionContext info

Tags: spring-batch

In a Spring Batch tasklet execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) method in a step that encrypts a file after the file has been written by previous steps, I need to access information in the job ExecutionContext.  It looks like I can get that information from either the stepContribution:

`stepContribution.getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext()`

or the chunkContext:

`chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext()`.

Will that always be the case? Or are there cases where the stepContribution will have a reference to the execution context but the chunkContext will be null or where there could be some other relevant difference between the chunkContext and the stepContribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job execution reference will always be the same whether you access it from the chunk context or from the step contribution.